# Remove querystring through web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

On my website, I have a situation where my URL sometimes get a querystring parameter appended by a system outsite ours.

So instead of looking like this: `http://www.domain.com?myquery=blah` or `http://www.domain.com`, it has the url `http`: `http://www.domain.com?myquery=blah&theirpara=blah` or `http://www.domain.com?theirpara=blah` .

When a user visits with the "theirpara" parameter, I would like to make a 301 redirect to the URL without it.

I've tried using the URL rewrite module, but not really getting anywhere. It would be nice to do it at IIS/web.config level instead of Response.RedirectPermanent if possible.

I thought it would be good to setup up using a rule (URL write module), but to be honest, I've no idea how to fix this issue. I am using the following rule to remove the trailing slash, but not sure how to modify it to this need.

```xml
<!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Any ideas on how to set it up?

Comment: What's wrong with their parameter, that you want to remove it?

Comment: Uriil: Search engine optimization purposes :) It gets indexed in Google, giving me duplicate content. It could be fixed with canonical url's, but I would like both solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an IIS to hand but the following should be working:

Change match to

```
<match url="(.*)&theirpara=blah(.*)" />
```

and redirect to

```
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}{R:2}" />
```

If you want it to work not only on the plain domain you should remove the conditions accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a pretty generic rule that removes `theirpara` but keeps any other query string parameters then you will have to handle cases where

1. It is alone: `?theirpara=123` -> `/`
2. It is first: `?theirpara=123&ourparams=456` -> `?ourparams=456`
3. It is in the middle: `?our1=123&theirpara=456&our2=789` -> `?our1=123&our2=789`
4. It is last: `?ourparams=123&theirpara=456` -> `?ourparams=123`

I wrote a rule that handles these cases but in case 4 a trailing ampersand is left, I hope it is enough to get you started though.

```
<rule name="Redirect on theirpara" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^(.*)theirpara=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;?(.*)$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:0}?{C:1}{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I have try your rules but it's not working for me.
When I try to test pattern  it's show an error. http://prntscr.com/nf4wil

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara. I think you shouldn't use &amp; in that dialog. Just using & should be enough.

Comment: My pattern us **^(.*)theirpara=([^=&]+)&?(.*)$** but website contain ? and & at last.
ex: http://example.com?
http://example.com?otherparam=valueofother&

Comment: What happen if **theirpara** is not into URL.
In my case throw an error, can't able to access website url without **theirpara**